# Is there a cap on storing many readings per second to Google Fit?

Tags: google-fit

I have an app that pumps multiple sensor readings per second to Google Fit.  When I read the data back, I get a fraction of the original readings.  Is there a cap on the amount of readings I can push to the cloud ?  If so, is there a link with this documentation ?

Documentation link:
https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#insert_data